# power analysis for binomial test

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

I am trying to test whether the sex ratio of some sampled individuals significantly differs from the expected sex ratio of 1. I have n= 64, of which female=34 and male=30.

I ran a binomial test:

```
succ <- c(34,30) 
binom.test(succ,0.5)

data:  succ
number of successes = 34, number of trials = 64, p-value = 0.708
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4023098 0.6572035
sample estimates:
probability of success 
               0.53125
```

I would like to calculate the statistical power of this test, and I know that *power = 1-β*, where β is the type II error.

I am getting confused when reading this [explanation](https://sites.calvin.edu/scofield/courses/m343/F15/handouts/binomialTestPower.pdf). I don't understand how to adapt this formula (for different choices of n) to my case:

```
enn = 1:2000
critical = qbinom(.025, enn, .5)
beta = pbinom(enn-critical,enn,.55) - pbinom(critical-1,enn,.55)
```

What I did was

```
1-(pbinom(34,64,0.5)- pbinom(30, 64, .5))
[1] 0.7410237
```

but I am not sure if it is correct to use 0.5 as probability.
Moreover, I tried a different method, and I get a completely different result

```
pwr.p.test(ES.h(.53125,.5),n=64, power=NULL, alternative = "two.sided")

 proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = 0.06254076
              n = 64
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.07913605
    alternative = two.sided
```

Is one of these two tests correct and why?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to find 'power', you need to have a specific alternative in mind.
Suppose your null hypothesis is $H_0: p = 0.5$ vs. $H_a: p > 0.5,$ where
$p = P(\mathrm{Female}).$ Also suppose you have $n = 64$ and you want the power
of a test at level $\alpha = 0.05$ against the specific alternative $p = 0.6.$

For an exact binomial test, you need to find the critical value $c$ such
that $P(X \ge c\,|\,n=64, p=.5)$ is maximized, but still below $0.05.$ In R,
where `dbinom`, `pbinom`, and `qbinom` denote binomial PDF, CDF, and quantile function (inverse CDF), respectively, we see that the critical value is $c = 40.$ Notice that, because of
the discreteness of binomial distributions, the so-called `5% level' actually rejects with probability
$P(\mathrm{Rej}\, H_0 | H_0\, \mathrm{True}) \approx 3\%.$

```
qbinom(.95, 64, .5)
[1] 39
sum(dbinom(39:64, 64, .5))
[1] 0.05171094
sum(dbinom(40:64, 64, .5))
[1] 0.02997059
1 - pbinom(39, 64, .5)
[1] 0.02997059
```

Then the power of this test against alternative value $p = 0.6$ is given by
$P(X \ge 40\,|\,n=64, p=0.6) = 0.3927.$

```
1 - pbinom(39, 64, .6)
[1] 0.392654
```

We can make a 'power curve' for this test by looking at a sequence of
alternative values `p.a` between $0.5$ and $.75.$ The first block of
R code below makes the solid black line in the plot below.

```
p.a = seq(.50, .75, by=.01)
p.rej = 1 - pbinom(39, 64, p.a)
plot(p.a, p.rej, type="l", main="Power Curve")
 abline(h=c(.03,1), col="green2")
```

[image]

If we look at a level $\alpha = 0.05$ test of $H_0: p = 0.5$ vs $H_a: p > 0.5$ with $n = 256$ subjects, then the critical value is $c = 141,$ the rejection probability when $H_0$ is true is $0.046,$ and the power against various
alternative values of $p$ is greater, as shown by the dotted blue line
in the figure.

```
c.256 = qbinom(.95, 256, .5); c.256
[1] 141
1 - pbinom(c.256, 256, .5)
[1] 0.04565604
p.rej.256 = 1 - pbinom(c.256, 256, p.a)
lines(p.a, p.rej.256, col="blue", lty="dotted")
```

*Notes:* Because $n = 64$ is sufficiently large to use normal approximations, you might want to try using normal approximations. A disadvantage is that this
ignores the issue of discreteness, so it may appear that your test rejects exactly 5% of the time when $H_0$ is true. Also, you'd need to use a continuity correction for
best results.

One relevant computation for the significance level in R is:

```
1 - pnorm(39.5, 32, 4)
[1] 0.03039636
```

(Approximate) power is $0.3895:$

```
mu.a = 64*.6;  sg.a = sqrt(64*.6*.4)
mu.a; sg.a
[1] 38.4
[1] 3.919184

1 - pnorm(39.5, mu.a, sg.a)     # Using NORM(mu.a, sg.a)
[1] 0.3894815
1 - pnorm((39.5 - mu.a)/sg.a)   # Standardizing and using NORM(0,1).
[1] 0.3894815
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also important to ask yourself why you are calculating the power.  Since you already have the data, you are calculating a 'post-hoc' power statistic (as opposed to a pre-hoc power statistic).  It's worth nothing that a number of authors have criticised the use of post-hoc power statistics from a Frequentist point of view - see, for example, https://gpsych.bmj.com/content/32/4/e100069