# Difference in the results of qbinom() and sensR::findcr() in R

Tags: binomial-distribution, critical-value

I try to understand the difference of +/-1 in the result of two functions using the binomial distribution.

I need to know the critical value of a situation where I have n=9 tests, the probability of success of each one is prob = 1/10 and the type I error is 0.05.

With `sensR::findcr(sample.size=9, alpha=0.05, p0=1/10, test="difference")`, the result is 4.

And with `qbinom(size = 9, p=0.95, prob = 1/10)`, the result is 3.

I tried with other sample sizes and success probabilities, out of curiosity, and this +/-1 difference is still there.

I read this [conversation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485577/power-analysis-for-binomial-test) and saw the same difference of 1 (the line is "we see that the critical value is c=40" but it refers to `qbinom(.95, 64, .5)` which gives 39).

I feel stupid because there is clearly something obvious that I do not understand, could someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: what kind of test are you considering?

Comment: a 2-out-of-5 test for 2 similar cosmetic products tested by 9 panelists

Comment: The only way to answer this is to consult the documentation (or code) for `sensR::findcr`.  I suspect it's just a difference in convention, concerning whether an inequality or a strict inequality is used in defining the critical value.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it seems to be a inequality vs strict inequality thing